# How to posting to joomla using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, api, joomla, posting

I want to write a program that can post data into joomla using C# via POST method. 

I have no idea to do that.

I hope someone help me some ideas.

joomla have any API support that ?

for ex something like xml-rpc in wordpress which support tag, category and  etc

I was used from XML-RPC for wordpress and also i see xml-rpc in joomla and I try for sending post with xml-rpc to joomla but i think that is not possible in joomla...

If we can send post to joomla via xml-rpc anyone can help me , that how possible..?

In wordpress i used from this code but this is not work with joomla.... :

```
blogInfo newBlogPost = default(blogInfo);
newBlogPost.title = wptitle;
newBlogPost.description = wpdescription;
newBlogPost.categories = wpcategories;//new string[] { "a","b" };
newBlogPost.mt_keywords = wptag;// new string[] { "t1", "t2" };


var categories = (IgetCatList)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IgetCatList));
var clientProtocol = (XmlRpcClientProtocol)categories;
clientProtocol.Url = link + "/xmlrpc.php";
string result = "";

result = categories.NewPage(1, user, pass, newBlogPost, 1);
```

Have any solution for send post to joomla via any api or etc ?

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: So you are on Joomla 1.5?

Comment: Joomla 3 does not have an xml-rpc application built in but you should use JInput to get data from a request http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput. Also if you really want xmlrpc you can look at some plugins that are out htere lke http://agichevski.com/2013/03/02/install-xmlrpc-api-on-joomla/  or http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/blog-integration/16655  just as two examples.

Comment: @Elin I checked that but with JInput  and also with xml-rpc(on v3) we can't send post to joomla....are you sure with JInput  we can send post ? have any example for send post ?

Comment: Joomla 3.2 is supposed to have support for REST, look into it or find a 3rd party implementation http://techjoomla.com/rest-api-for-joomla.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also connect to the database directly from your C# application and import data to the right tables with caution.
Another way is to create a simple component, in order to post the data "however" you want and manage them properly.